# Unable to Download OneNote file using Microsoft Graph API - 503 ServiceUnavailable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to download OneNote (.one) file from the OneDrive using MS Graph API but always get 503 Service Unavailable Error.
I have tried 2 ways of downloading it.

First, using the URL available through the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property on the DriveItem.

> GET /users/{userId}/drive/items/{item-id}

Then, I tried to download the content using this endpoint

> GET /users/{userId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content

But the result is the same. It returns 503 Service Unavailable Error.

Any idea what is the cause?

The file size is around 2.5 GB. Is the big OneNote size make it failed to download?

Thanks

Comment: File size is huge, i believe it might be timing out. Just to isolate the issue out of your application, try the above API call in POSTMAN/Graph explorer as well. Share the requestid, timestamp of the detailed error.

Comment: Do you have any updates?